# Initialize DrawString() in switch function of C#

Tags: c#, xna

I am using XNA and C#, I use switch function like:

```
switch (state)
{
    case GameState.MainMenu:
        Score = 1;
        equation.Draw(spriteBatch);//for the equation
        break;

    case GameState.TutorialSelect:
        Score2 = 1;
        equation.Draw(spriteBatch);//for the equation
        break;
}
```

In my equation function, I have:

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    if (Score == 1)
    {
        spriteBatch.DrawString(
            Font,                          
            "AAAAAAAAA",  
            scorePos,                     
            Color.White);
    }

    if (Score2 == 1)
    {
        spriteBatch.DrawString(
            Font,                          
            "BBBBBBBBBBBBB",  
            scorePos3,                     
            Color.White);
    }
}
```

In my situation, I want to clear the DrawString() when I switch from "GameState.MainMenu" and "GameState.TutorialSelect", How to fix the problem please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't be a problem, because you *always* clear the surface when drawing for this exact reason. Otherwise, when anything changed (due to animation, etc.) you would have artifacts left over.

Your draw function should look like this:

```
public void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

    //All your code
}
```

If you are referring to *both* drawing, then that is because you don't unset your "Score" variable on the switch. You need to do:

```
switch (state)
{
    case GameState.MainMenu:
        Score = 1;
        Score2 = 0;
        equation.Draw(spriteBatch);//for the equation
        break;

    case GameState.TutorialSelect:
        Score2 = 1;
        Score = 0;
        equation.Draw(spriteBatch);//for the equation
        break;
}
```

That logic is really messed up anyways; I would just switch on `state` again; but thats just me.